# Give initial file name value to Vuetify v-file-input

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have this html in my template:

```html
        <v-file-input
          :label="label"
          accept="image/*"
          prepend-icon="mdi-camera"
          @change="uploadImage"
          hide-details
          outlined
        />
```

My component also has a prop called `current` which contains a text which is the name of the current file.

When the component is displayed the `v-file-input` is empty but I want it to include the name of the current file name. I've tried `:value="current"` and `v-model="current"` to no avail.

What should I do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `value` prop. But it doesn't accept strings. From the docs:

> value - A single or array of [File objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File)

So for example this works:

```js
data() {
    return {
      current: new File(["foo"], "foo.txt", {
                  type: "text/plain",
                })
    }
  }
```

```html
<v-file-input label="File input" :value="current" ></v-file-input>
```

Whether it's a good idea to do this is different question :) You know, what you have is not just file name, its whole file including content. What if user submits your form like this? Also support for `File()` [constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/File) is not that great....will not work on Edge for example...

Comment: 2022 Update: File() is supported on all major browsers https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/File#browser_compatibility

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `placeholder` attribute for this:

```
<v-file-input label="File input" :placeholder="current" ></v-file-input>
```

The style might be a bit different than the "normal" text but a bit of css can probably fix that.

Comment: I am trying to do that you are specifying (it is 100% logical) but only appears placeholder when I focus in the component

Answer (score 0):

Instead use a computed property, since props are immutable and use value for data binding `v-model="value"`

```
computed () {
    value: {
      get () {
        return this.current
      },
      set (val) {
        this.value = val
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Workaround:

DOM:

```
<v-file-input v-model="file" class="v-file-input"></v-file-input>
```

CSS:

```
/**/
.v-file-input label {
    /**/
    transform: translateY(-6px) scale(.75) !important;
    /**/
}
```

JS:

```
/**/
new Vue({
    /**/
    el: "#app",
    /**/
    vuetify: vuetify,
    /**/
    data: () => ({
        /**/
        default: {
            /**/
            name: null,
            /**/
            size: null,
            /**/
        },
        /**/
        file: null,
        /**/
    }),
    /**/
    updated(){
        /**/
        $(".v-file-input").find(".v-file-input__text").html(this.file ? `<div>${this.file.name} (${this.readableBytes(this.file.size)})</div>` : this.default.name ? `<div>${this.default.name} (${this.readableBytes(this.default.size)})</div>` : "");
        /**/
    },
    /**/
    methods: {
        /**/
        readableBytes: function(x){
            /**/
            const units = ["B", "KB", "MB", "GB", "TB", "PB", "EB", "ZB", "YB"];
            /**/
            var i = 0, n = parseInt(x, 10) || 0;
            /**/
            while(n >= 1024 && ++i){
                /**/
                n = n / 1024;
                /**/
            }
            /**/
            return n.toFixed(n < 10 && i > 0 ? 1 : 0) + " " + units[i];
            /**/
        },
    }
});
```